# MAUI Blazor App raises an Exception when running on Debug mode on physical Android device

Tags: maui-blazor

I am developing an App using MAUI and Visual Studio 2022 Preview.
When I run on my Windows laptop, all right. 
Also, if I tap and launch the App on the Android device (without Debugging) it runs normally.
But when I run Debugging on my phisical Android device, it throws this exception:

```
$exception  {System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
File name: 'System.Private.CoreLib.resources'
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(Assembly assembly, CultureInfo culture, Version version, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound)} System.IO.FileNotFoundException
```

[image: Screenshot]

I had enabled all Common Language Runtime Exceptions:
[image: Exception settings]

```
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly pt/System.Private.CoreLib.resources.dll
**System.IO.FileNotFoundException:** ''

[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly pt/System.Private.CoreLib.resources.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly pt-BR/System.Private.DataContractSerialization.resources.dll
**System.IO.FileNotFoundException:** ''

[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly pt-BR/System.Private.DataContractSerialization.resources.dll
```

How to solve this?

Comment: I found out that if I click Continue a few times, then the app runs in Debug mode.

Comment: that "Common Language Runtime Runtime Exceptions" you check will make your project raise EVERY exception the CLR raises. You don't need to be aware of ALL those exceptions. From that same "Excepetion Setting"s window you have a button to "Restore the list to the default settings"

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71792563/net-maui-application-fails-to-launch-on-local-arm64-v8a-device

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to toggle the FileNotFoundException in the Exception Settings **when the app is NOT running**.
It doesn't work if the app is currently launched in Debug mode.

[image: FileNotFoundException]

Comment: How do you get to the Exceptions Settings window without launching in Debug mode?

Comment: Just go in Menu > Debug > Windows > Exception Settings