# .net MAUI application fails to launch on local arm64-v8a device

Tags: android, .net, build, arm64, maui

I've developed MAUI application. Eveything works perfectly on emulator and I want to try it out on my Xiaomi Redmi note 9. But it fails with:

```
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.mauieventsamplecs/files/.__override__/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly lt-LT/System.Private.CoreLib.resources.dll
[chatty] uid=10359(com.companyname.mauieventsamplecs) identical 2 lines
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly lt-LT/System.Private.CoreLib.resources.dll
[uieventsamplec] Process terminated due to "Infinite recursion during resource lookup within System.Private.CoreLib.  This may be a bug in System.Private.CoreLib, or potentially in certain extensibility points such as assembly resolve events or CultureInfo names.  Resource name: IO_FileName_Name"
[libc] Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 1418 (uieventsamplecs), pid 1418 (uieventsamplecs)
```

I pinpointed that it's the problem of different CPU. By default, the app is building on `Any CPU` (emulator runs `x86_64` system). Which I would hope should include `arm64-v8a`, but it seems to only include all Intel CPU. Tried launching `arm64-v8a` emulator, but it's not supported since my device is `Intel` and not `AMD`

I tried changeing solution platform to `ARM64`, but ether that did not help or, you need to something more than just adding new solution platform and assigning it to actually make it work.

So my question is: how one should set up the MAUI to launch on local `arm64-v8a` if that's even possible.

Comment: Even when you see that exception, you can continue (F5) about 3 times, then the app appears

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was the problem based on `lt-LT/System.Private.CoreLib.resources.dll` After few days of debugging and finally switching my phone language from `LT` to `US` in my phone settings it fixed the problem.

Comment: Although you cannot ask that of your users, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I got a notification for this post even though I never commented on it - which is odd - but turns out I have something to offer anyway. :-)

In regards to your comment about having to change the language, turns out this was (potentially) fixed just the other day. There was a bug in System.Private.Corelib which ONLY affected Android apps in Debug mode if not using English (U.S.). This has now been fixed (at least as far as that specific infinite recursion bug anyways, but possibly related to yours as well) - fixed in Visual Studio 17.5.0 https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/7745#event-8795560371

Answer (score -1):

Try set in MauiApp1.csproj

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <!--<RuntimeIdentifiers>android-arm;android-arm64;android-x86;android-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>-->
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>android-arm;android-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
</PropertyGroup>
```